# Use select query anywhere in the project in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to use select query in my model class without instantiating Zend_Db::factory() because I have given all the parameters of database in application.ini.My database name is mst2.
My model class is as follows:

```
 class Application_Model_EmpIdMapper extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
 {

     public function checkEmpid($empId)
     {
          $select=$this->select()
                        ->from(array('tc' => 'tcs_contact'),array('tc.employee_id'));
          $table_data=$this->fetchAll($select);
          $table_data=$table_data->toArray();
          foreach($table_data as $row) 
          { 

                  // don check the condition before putting it into for each loop
                 if($row['employee_id'] == $empId)
                 { 
                    return 'true'; 
                 } 
                 else
                 {
                   return 'false';
                 }

             } 

           } 


        }
```

but ruuning the application gives the error as

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
>   'mst2.application_model_empidmapper' doesn't exist.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the table name in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Model class:

```
// the actual name of the table in the database
protected $_name = 'the_name_of_your_Table_you_want_to_use';
```

Comment: I dont want to specify the particular table name in model class as I have to perform operations on multiple tables using join.In that case what should be done??

Comment: I think that´s not a problem at all. If I´m not totally mistaken you have to call $select->setIntegrityCheck(false); to perform joins over multiple tables (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.advanced.usage Example 27).